# Реализация на PHP отправки с сервера на мессенджер

Tags: php

Пользователь заполняет поле на сайте и нажимает отправить, информация тут же отправляется на мессенджер оператора (без разницы, какой мессенджер или qip, или miranda и т.д.). 
На каком языке можно организовать отправку с сервера на мессенджер? Можно ли это сделать на php, нужны ли для этого какие-нибудь библиотеки?

Я делаю что-то похожее на krible.ru и livetex.ru (сервисы предоставляющие по для онлайн консультации на сайте).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если под мессенджером вы понимаете XMPP-клиент, то для PHP есть библиотека [XMPPHP](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/), которая и предназначена для отправки сообщений через XMPP сервер.

Comment: Смогу ли я отправить с помощью данной библеотеки сообщение с сервера на qip?

Comment: Qip - это клиент. Вы будете отправлять сообщение не клиенту, а абоненту. Если он подключен к учетке по XMPP, то вы отправите сообщение абоненту, если по ICQ - нет.

Comment: Всё, я понял. Похоже это по, что мне нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Для ICQ есть класс [WebICQPro](http://wip.asminog.com/workshop/webicqpro/webicqpro.html)